# Check if String starts with string

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am lead iOS dev on an application and it's a long story but our freelance API dev is 'unavailable'. So I'm a complete newbie to laravel/PHP and trying to fix a bug on our API.

Basically, when a user signs up by default we take their Facebook profile picture and save it's URL in the database as their profile picture for the app. When they add a custom picture it is saved with a random alphanumeric string save and that string is set in the `profile_pic` column. When the `profile_pic`is returned within the `JSON` object our base URL is appended to the start.

So the problem is that this base URL is also appended to the start of the Facebook image URL so that it would look like `https://base.url/https://facebook.url` which means a user won't see the image, just the default placeholder grey colour. I would like to be able to check whether the URL already starts with a certain value.

This is what I have so far:

```
public function getProfilePicAttribute($value){
     $fbUrl = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net"
     $length = strlen($fbUrl);
     if (substr($value, 0, $length) === $fbUrl) {
         return $value
     }
     return 'https://' . env('VDT_DOMAIN') . '/uploads/profile_pic/' . $value;
}
```

This doesn't work so I was wondering if anybody would be able to help me out with it. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Laravel has great [`starts_with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-starts-with) helper. For example, this will return `true`:

```
starts_with('This is my name', 'This');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm sorry to be a pain but would you be able to show how this works in the context of my code?

Comment: After laravel 6 string helpers are deprecated so this solution becomes `Str::startsWith('This is my name', 'This');`

Answer (score 3):

You can use Str::startsWith() helper...

```
\Illuminate\Support\Str::startsWith('This is my string', 'This');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of truncating the string to compare, you can use `strpos` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
if (strpos($value, $fbURL) === 0) {
    return $value;
}
return 'https://' . env('VDT_DOMAIN') . '/uploads/profile_pic/' . $value;
```

Comment: As noted in the docs, be sure to use `===` because "This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."  So doing `=== 0` is checking if it starts with the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still getting a 500 returned when using this - do you know what the problem might be? Sorry if I'm asking really newbie questions!

Comment: I've just noticed the second variable in `strpos` is incorrect - I'll change that first and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

this is to show the  usage of the method indicated above by Alexey

```
    public function getProfilePicAttribute($value){
    $fbUrl = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net";
 $length = strlen($fbUrl);

    if(starts_with($fbUrl, 'base.url')){

    return $value;
    }


     return 'https://' . env('VDT_DOMAIN') . '/uploads/profile_pic/' . $value;
```

where the base.url is whatever url is getting concatenated before the value